# Crossdomian ajax requests to server returned json object shows error Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, express, cross-domain

I am running an express server in which I am checking for get requests to certain url requests. Now in the reply I am trying to send a reply in json format so that I can make ajax calls to the page and get data. Now to make cross domain requsts I had to use jsonp. Now when the request is completed and the data is returned to the callback it shows error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`.
Here are the server and client codes below

Server

```
var express=require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var port=Number(3000);
var server_ip_address = '127.0.0.1';

http.listen(port,server_ip_address, function(){
   console.log('listening on '+port);
});

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.query);
   res.send({message:'hello'});
});
```

Client

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/test',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType:'jsonp',
    crossDomain:true,
    data: {
        username: $('#username').val(),
        password: $('#pwd').val()
    },
    success: function(result){
        console.log($.parseJSON(result));
    },
    jsonp:'jsonp'
});
```

In the server code i have tried using

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
res.send({message:'recieved'});
```

even

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.send({message:'recieved'});
```

In the client i have tried logging the result object as it is but to no avail. Any help is appreciated. Moreover any suggestions to use other methods to fetch data are equally welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is just use `res.jsonp()` rather than setting your own headers etc:

```
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.query);
   res.jsonp({message: 'hello'});
});
```

The default callback parameter is just `callback` but you can change it (if you need to) like so:

```
app.set('jsonp callback name', 'cb');
```

*note*: You might have to remove the `jsonp:'jsonp'` from your client-side code as that assigned the name of the callback. I'd also suggest you swap it from a GET to a POST request if you are submitting data (especially sensitive data).

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Learnt that res.jsonp function exists.

Comment: No problem, [here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.jsonp) is the documentation link about `res.jsonp`, there is also just `res.json` for non-cross domain requests.